# I want to make HTTP call for Desktop application (can call from Command line)

Tags: java, web-services, command-line

I have one Desktop application and i want to call that applicating using command line from anothr web application. is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

A desktop application being the target of a call is usually a bad idea because in order to succeed the desktop application must be visible from where you want to reach it. This *might* or *might not* be a problem.

If the 2 computers are on a LAN, this should not be a problem. If the desktop application is behind a router or firewall, this requires opening and forwarding a port to the computer the desktop application is running on. This might not be *feasible* or doable (e.g. you have no permission to change firewall and routing settings) in many cases.

Best approach would be for the desktop application to contact the web server.

But if you really want to do otherwise, the desktop application should create a [`ServerSocket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) and listen for incoming connections, or start an embedded web server. There are other possibilities of course (e.g. [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation)).